# Returning string from class library using Nuget package "NetCoreServer"

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient, class-library

I am writing a Windows Form application (TCP Client) using the Nuget package "NetCoreServer".
I have implemented the methods specified in the example "TcpChatClient", see: [TcpChatClient](https://github.com/chronoxor/NetCoreServer/blob/master/examples/TcpChatClient/Program.cs). This works just fine, and I am able to pass messages back and forth to and from a server and display the messages in the Windows Form.

However, due to reusability (the next TCP Client application might be a console application), I would like to limit the code in the form class to just GUI stuff and move all networking logic to a class library. Basically, I would like the form class to just pass and receive strings to methods in the class library (from what I gather, this is best practice, for reusability).

I have successfully moved the code to a class library and debugging shows that the messages are sent back and forth the same as when I had all the code in the form class. But I am stuck on how to actually get the response from the class library to the form class.

In the class library the relevant code is:

```
protected override void OnReceived(byte[] buffer, long offset, long size)
{
    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, (int)offset, (int)size);
}
```

Since the "OnReceived" method is inherited from a class in the Nuget package, I am unable to change the signature, so I cannot get the method to return a string. This was my initial thought.
I feel like I am missing an obvious way to pass the string to the form class, but I just cant figure this out.

I have intentionally not posted much code in this question, but I can of course provide my code if elaboration is necessary.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The receive event does not have a return value. I usually create a FIFO in the class object. that the receive event adds data at the end.  Then application code reads from beginning of the FIFO.

Comment: Are you thinking something along these lines.
In the class library, add a public Queue<string> as a field.
Then in the OnReceived method, do enqueue on the Queue.
In the application, do dequeue and get the string? Should I then continuously monitor the queue to detect when data is received?

Comment: Yes.  I  like using WaitOne instead of using timers.  After getting a receive message set the waitOne so code looping will process the message : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-7.0

Comment: I have tried wrapping the update UI method in a Task.Run(), which seems to work OK. How would you use WaitOne to update the UI, based on a receive message (i.e. the FIFO queue count is larger than 0)?